# Numerical integral for periodic function

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Let $T>0,$ $w >\!\!> T$ and let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  be $T-$ periodic function.

I'd like to know whether there is a quadrature formula with number of points independent of $w$ for

$$I= \int_a^b f(w x)dx$$
which approximates $I$ at the order $\mathcal{O}(w^{-m})$ for some positive integer  $m.$

Thank you in advanced

Comment: If $g$ is periodic, wouldn't $f(g(x))$ also be periodic function of $x$?

Comment: There's quite a number of methods for oscillatory integrals, they work better for higher frequencies. The well known method is [Levin quadrature](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042794001189?via%3Dihub), which is suitable for a certain class of integrals and uses collocation. Some improvements of this method [have been published](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168927410000735). See also [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/64/19594) for a more general review.

Comment: Googling "numerical integration of oscillatory functions" also brings forward a lot of results and reviews. I have been trying to find such methods myself recently

Comment: what about Fourier & box function ?

Comment: Thank you for the comments.. @YuriyS I have been googling such methods but most of them are constructed for cases like $\int_a^b f(x)e^{iw g(x)}dx.$ I'm interested actually in integrating functions like $x\mapsto f(\sum_{k=0}^N \cos(a_k w x))$

Comment: @GCab Would you please clarify ?

Comment: @A.PI, what is $f$, can you specify what kind of functions are you interested in? And how large is $N$? Is there any relationship between $a_k$?

Comment: @YuriyS $f$ is some smooth function and let $N= 2, a_k =1$ and consider the integral  of $f(\alpha \sin(w x) + \beta \cos(w x)),$ where $\alpha, \beta$ are fixed real numbers.